# Javascript - Como eu monto um lista de inputs usando um array que é array de outro objeto

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Tenho um cenário para montar uma grade no `frontend`, mas que não estou conseguindo montar.

Recebo de meu `backend um JSON` que contem uma lista. Esta lista tem dois campos: Ordem e Tamanho, sendo que para montar em tela, o campo Ordem será o titulo(que vai de 00 a 14) e o tamanho será o valor do imput. Alguém sabe como posso implementar isso? Estou usando `AngularJS`.

Detalhe: depois de montado, e se for atualizado, devo retornar esses valores fazendo um novo parse para que isso volte para a lista original.
Agradeço desde já a ajuda.

Comment: Não entendi bem sua questão. Sua dúvida é sobre como passar esses dados que você recebe do banco para a tela no front end? Seria isso? Se sim, qual seu código em AngularJs que recebe os dados do backend?

Comment: Juvêncio, poste um exemplo do JSON recebido - isso ajudará a formulação de respostas.

Comment: CelsomTrindade, a minha dúvida e que eu recebo o JSON abaixo e preciso "montar" uma linha de imputs com Titulo(será o label) e Descrição(será o imput).CelsomTrindade, a minha dúvida e que eu recebo o JSON abaixo e preciso "montar" uma linha de imputs com Titulo(será o label) e Descrição(será o imput). Esse e o JSON: {"ID":1, "Descricao":"Grade de sapatos","gradeOrdem":[{"idGrade":1,"ID":1,"Ordem":"01","Tamanho":"38" },{"idGrade":1,"ID":2,   "Ordem":"02", "Tamanho":"39"},{"idGrade":1, "ID":3,  "Ordem":"03", "Tamanho":"40"},]}